# Fully customizable message box in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I would like to create a message box in my Windows Phone 7 application, but I want to add the "never show again" button or checkbox inside of it. How can I do that? I searched about it and I found examples in XNA and found a code using Notificationbox, but it doesn't seem to work with C# or something.

My project is coded with C#, is there a way to implement a customizable message box?

Comment: `but it seems not to work with C# or something`... please show code you tied.

Answer (score 3):

Tomer Shamam has an example of how to do this at:  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx

He's put the code on http://wpassets.codeplex.com/